# How to count the amount of times a tag has been used with ActsAsTaggableOn rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a dashboard in my project where I want to show all the tags I have in my project, along with the number of times those tags have been used. For tagging I use the ActsAsTaggableOn gem on my Post model.

I currently have a variable which shows the most used tags in my tagscontroller:

```
def index
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.most_used
end
```

And I can find the amount of tags a certain post has by going in to rails console and running

```
post = Post.first
post.tag_counts_on(:tags).count
```

however I can't figure out how to return the number of times each tag has been used on my Post model.

EDIT:

Thanks to Sam's answer below I managed to find the column in the tags model I wanted to call from (using the debug console). To call the amount of times each tag has been used I did:

```
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
```

In my tags controller and

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name %><%= tag.taggings_count %>
<% end %>
```

In my view.

Comment: `Post.all.tag_counts_on(:tags).size`?

Comment: That brings back the total number of tags I have, I'm trying to show the amount of times each individual tag has been used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#usage) and [this](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/collection.rb#L12), you should be able to:

```
Post.tag_counts
```

Given `:tags` is the "context" you used on the `Post` model.

Comment: when assigning this to a variable in my tags controller's index action (  @post = Post.tag_counts) and making sure the context is tags in the Post model (acts_as_taggable, same as acts_as_taggable_on :tags) I call the variable in my index file and for each tag I get `#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xaf8e838>`

Comment: That should be correct. Now you can iterate through and see the count of each Tag tagged to a post. Try `logger.debug(Post.tag_counts.to_a)` in your controller and check the development log.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being far too newbie at this point, I've added the logger.debug line under my current variables in the index action of my tagscontroller, but how do I view the log? I'm checking through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html and can't figure out how to view the log, do I just do <%= debug @posts %> in my index page or? edit - figured out how to show the log, just trying to look through it now :)

Comment: You can run `$ tail -f log/development.log` from the command-line (OS X or Linux). Or your `rails s` output should show the DEBUG line as well.

Comment: Okay I'm getting:
      values:
        id: 9
        name: Test
        taggings_count: 4
        count: 4

(I might be missing something here, but how does this relate to the post  model? i.e. can I use something from here to include in my variable - thanks for your help with this so far)

Comment: It was me being silly, I've figured it out and I'll update my question with the resolution, thanks for your help with this.